# Monorepo *nx affected:build* develop branch problem - JENKINS

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl, monorepo

I have multibranch pipeline created on my Jenkins server.

I have a full stack project made in node.js (nest.js and angular app as frontend). One every push i build the app that is affected by the last commit, with a command  `npm run nx affected:build --base=develop`.

When i get to the stage BUILD on my jenkins server after applying the above command i get this error:

```
nx "affected:build"

fatal: Not a valid object name master
Error: Command failed: git merge-base master HEAD

fatal: Not a valid object name master



at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:630:11)

at Object.execSync (child_process.js:666:15)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible reasons:

1. You need to pass proper git branch for staging CI build
2. Nx workspace changes haven't been merged to master or your stage git branch.

Make sure you have both covered.

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
nx affected:build --base=develop
```

Either

```
npm run nx affected:build -- --base=develop
```